# what is the full meaning of following line

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, ssl, python-2.7

what is the full meaning of following line

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:5050/$1 [L,P]
```

There are three application both running by python on ubuntu 14.4. they are visible as below link

```
IP:8181   (headphones)
IP:8081   (sickbeard)
IP:5050   (couchpotato)
```

i have also installed HTTPS on that server.
https://82.211.213.130/

But i want to rewrite above three site in the bellow way

```
same IP/couchpotato     -- this is working only
same IP/sickbeard   -- Not working
same IP/headphones  -- not working
```

when i want to view /sickbeard or  /headphones it allways comes couchpotato page.

can help me any one to solve this??

Apache config is as below --

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName lost-world.dk
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) localhost:5050/$1 [L,P]
   ProxyPreserveHost on
#   RequestHeader add X-Vhm-Root /couchpotato
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName lost-world.dk
  SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) localhost:8081/$1 [L,P]
   ProxyPreserveHost on
 #  RequestHeader add X-Vhm-Root /sickbeard
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking too many questions at once.  I'd recommend using `nginx`, as it is much, much easier to configure, especially when dealing with multiple Virtual Hosts.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:5050/$1
```

This is a Regular Expression (regex) rule that matches against url the user has visited.

This rule says 'Take all of the characters after the domain (www.example.tld/WHATEVER) and rewrite it as http://127.0.0.1:5050/WHATEVER.

The parentheses `( )` is called a 'capture', and the `$1` puts the first capture there.

You could try the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/couchpotato http://127.0.0.1:5050
```

The [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) provides some great real-world examples.

Comment: Wow!  Just +1 because you actually understood the question!   **@Masum:** As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**